# Cardinality of $X$ and of its power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Does it hold that $|X|=|Y|\iff |P(X)|=|P(Y)|$ where $X,Y$ are sets? I know that this holds for the finite case since $|P(X)|=2^{|X|}$ in that case, but what about the infinite case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It holds that
$$ |X|=|Y| \implies |\mathcal P(X)|=|\mathcal P(Y)| $$
(and it is easy to use a bijection $X\to Y$ to construct a bijection $\mathcal P(X)\to\mathcal P(Y)$.

The **opposite implication** is not necessarily true, though. It is neither provable nor disprovable from the usual axioms of set theory. If we assume the [generalized continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis#The_generalized_continuum_hypothesis), then it will be true, but the GCH is itself independent of the axioms and not generally expected to be true of the mathematical universe.

Comment: I would advise caution about that last statement. Also, this is clearly a duplicate...

Comment: @Asaf, that was the last statement before I edited, right?

Comment: Assuming GCH, suppose the power sets have cardinality $\aleph_\alpha$. Then both sets are forced to have cardinality $\aleph_{\alpha-1}$, since any other $\aleph_\beta$ would not give a power set of cardinality $\aleph_\alpha$. Is that correct?

Comment: @MickG: Yes, correct.

Comment: And naturally a bijection $f:X\to Y$ induces a bijection between the powersets by setting $Z\mapsto f(Z)$ for any subset $Z\subseteq X$.